# Ubuntu on iMac: graphics

Tags: imac, unix, gpu

I have just got a new iMac 14.3 with 21.5″ display. It has Intel i7 processor and NVIDIA GeForce GT750M graphics card with GPU (Device ID: 0x00fe9). I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on it (dual boot with refit). Everything works fine apart from graphics. It is clear that graphics' not accelerated. I have tried to…

1. Install NVIDIA drivers from the repository.
2. Download NVIDIA drivers and install them manually.
3. Follow instructions [here](http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/).
4. Follow instructions [here](http://dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html).
5. Follow instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver).
6. Install bumblebee.
7. Play around with xorg.conf file.
8. Blacklist nouveau.

As you may guess, nothing worked. The weirdest thing is, that when I boot from a LiveCD, it picks up screen resolution and all the rest correctly, though when I install the system to my Hard Drive it clearly does not have proper drivers. I have checked it with lsmod and it seems that it pick up nouveau drivers in LiveCD mode — everything works fine then, but it does not in the install mode — get crap resolution. Also, I cannot load nouveau drivers manually. In case this is important, I have to boot with `acpi=off` option, as it does not boot otherwise. Does anyone have any suggestion how can I fix this graphics problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is actually very simple: just boot with `nolapic` instead of `acpi=off`.